# Set Exchange Mailbox quota if total item size less then

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, quota

I have a need to set Mailbox quotas to 2GB. but sines I have some users how already pass 2GB, I want leave them out with no limit. (or to apply 4GB limit to them).
I been playing for some time with WHERE parameter, but no success so far.

would love to get some help!

Comment: Add what you have tried so far...

Answer (score 0):

Get-Mailbox -Server  | `
  Get-MailboxStatistics | Where {$_.TotalItemSize -lt 2GB} | Set-Mailbox -IssueWarningQuota 1536MB -ProhibitSendQuota 2GB -ProhibitSendReceiveQuota 2150MB -UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults $false

It is so simple. Sorry for asking.

Comment: please edit the original question and put the code in code tags instead of posting this as an answer.